# Get Sum in month with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL where I display the total by month:

```
select to_char(tanggal, 'mm') as month, 
      sum(nilai) as realisasi
    from 
      tbl_pasar_dini 
    where (date_part('year', tanggal)= extract(year from timestamp 'NOW()')) 
    group by 1
```

and this is the result:

| month | realisasi |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2000 |
| 02 | 900 |
| 03 | 3000 |
| 04 | 200 |
| 05 | 5000 |
| 06 | 100 |

How do I make the total accumulate, so that each month the value increases from the previous month

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: for example in the first month the realization has a total of 2000, then in the second month it gets 900

so in the second month it should be, the first month + the income of the second month, so it should be 2900... and so on

Comment: take a look on this article, it has the answer for you problem https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am interpreting from your question you want the total sum of every realisasi value of all the months int the current given year of 2021. So you could either reuse your given query and do this

```
select sum(realisasi) from (/* the select query you given */)
```

or just a little modification to just get the entire sum

```
select sum(nilai) as realisasi
    from 
      tbl_pasar_dini 
    where (date_part('year', tanggal)= extract(year from timestamp 'NOW()'))
```

if you could also provide your table structure it would help.

Edit: so from your new comment what you want is a running sum from each month. If so then you have to use the OVER clause.

```
select to_char(tanggal, 'mm') as month,
      sum(sum(nilai)  OVER (ORDER BY month)) as realisasi
    from 
      tbl_pasar_dini 
    where (date_part('year', tanggal)= extract(year from timestamp 'NOW()')) 
    group by 1
```

Comment: please help on my query